# Memcached authentication failure in Java app

Tags: java, heroku, memcached, spymemcached

I'm busy following Heroku's Memcached tutorial for Java: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/memcache#using-spymemcached-with-spring

I have installed Memcached via homebrew, got it up and running, added the Spymemcached dependency and added the XML config to my application context.

The problem is I haven't got the faintest clue as to what the MEMCACHE_USERNAME and MEMCACHE_PASSWORD environment variables needs to be as I get the following authentication failures when my application context boots up locally:

```
2013-04-21 18:22:52.108 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Added {QA sa=localhost/127.0.0.1:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0} to connect queue
2013-04-21 18:22:52.127 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@228ef305
2013-04-21 18:22:52.283 WARN net.spy.memcached.auth.AuthThread:  Authentication failed to localhost/127.0.0.1:11211
2013-04-21 18:22:52.398 WARN net.spy.memcached.auth.AuthThread:  Authentication failed to localhost/127.0.0.1:11211
2013-04-21 18:22:52.520 WARN net.spy.memcached.auth.AuthThread:  Authentication failed to localhost/127.0.0.1:11211 ...
```

The config where the username and password is provided:

```
<bean id="plainCallbackHandler" class="net.spy.memcached.auth.PlainCallbackHandler">
   <constructor-arg index="0" value="${MEMCACHE_USERNAME}"/>
   <constructor-arg index="1" value="${MEMCACHE_PASSWORD}"/>
</bean>
```

I must be missing something fairly obvious... Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the app locally, the `MEMCACHE_USERNAME` and `MEMCACHE_PASSWORD` should both be blank (unless you set them during the install). You can run your app with the prefix `MEMCACHE_USERNAME= MEMCACHE_PASSWORD= the-command-to-run-your-app` if your configuration doesn't handle null values.

If you are running on Heroku with the Memcache addon, you will get the environment variables like `MEMCACHE_USERNAME`, `MEMCACHE_PASSWORD`, and `MEMCACHE_SERVERS`, which are set automatically when you install the add-on.

If you self-host your Memcached servers, you will have to (or *should*) set a SASL username and password that you will configure in your application.

Comment: Hi Benjamin - thanks for your answer. I tried your suggestion and made MEMCACHE_USERNAME and MEMCACHE_PASSWORD blank, but without success. Is there perhaps a way to see what the credentials are or do you think I should rather reinstall Memcached and try again?

Comment: Try running `telnet localhost 11211` to access the Memcached telnet interface. If you can connect, type a command like `version` or `stats` to see if you have access. If you get a response, that means that your Memcached server is running and has no authentication - so the problem would be elsewhere.

Comment: Ok so I managed to connect via telnet and successfully ran version and stats. Any ideas where the problem could lie?

Comment: FYI I did reinstall Memcached via homebrew, it never asks me for an username or password, and still I get the authentication failure...

Answer (score 0):

HI，I also encountered a similar problem, because I did not set a SASL username and password, so when I deleted the configuration, the error message disappeared.

```
<bean name="defaultCache" class="com.google.code.ssm.CacheFactory">
    <property name="cacheName" value="default" />
    <property name="cacheClientFactory">
        <bean name="cacheClientFactory"
            class="com.google.code.ssm.providers.spymemcached.MemcacheClientFactoryImpl" />
    </property>
    <property name="addressProvider" ref="addressProvider" />
    <property name="configuration" ref="cacheFactoryConf" />
</bean>

<bean id="addressProvider" class="com.google.code.ssm.config.DefaultAddressProvider">
    <property name="address" value="${memcached.hosts}" />
</bean>
<bean id="cacheFactoryConf"
    class="com.google.code.ssm.providers.spymemcached.SpymemcachedConfiguration">
    <property name="consistentHashing" value="true" />
    <property name="useBinaryProtocol" value="true" />
    <property name="keyPrefixSeparator" value=".xxx." />
    <property name="useNameAsKeyPrefix" value="true" />
    <!-- 
    <property name="authDescriptor">
        <bean class="net.spy.memcached.auth.AuthDescriptor">
            <constructor-arg index="0">
                <value>PLAIN</value>
            </constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg index="1">
                <bean class="net.spy.memcached.auth.PlainCallbackHandler">
                    <constructor-arg index="0">
                        <value>${memcached.username}</value>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <constructor-arg index="1">
                        <value>${memcached.password}</value>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
    -->
</bean>
```